# F string assignment from a different file?

Tags: python, f-string

I like to keep one file with just my f strings that represents SQL queries and each query needs a db name. In my python program, i will populate the db variable as I am reading out db names.

E.g.
in `queries.py`, i have

```
query_1 = f"select * from {db} limit 10;"
```

in `main.py`, i use

```
from quries import quries
# read out db information into dbs
for db in dbs:
  # execute the query_1 for each db
```

How can I achieve the logic in the loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use an f-string, but `.format()`

```py
# queries
query_1 = "select * from {db} limit 10;"
```

```py
from queries import query_1
...
for db in dbs:
    query = query_1.format(db=db)
    ...
```

Comment: Ok..what is f string good for?

Comment: @drdot ... for interpolating strings with valid expressions and format specifiers....

Comment: just so - it's useful for some immediate output and less useful for templating .. and you could, for example use `{{}}` to format _again_ to have an f-string you can format into! however, beware of making something non-obvious and horrible, etc.